# Facet Grid Title and Labels

Tags: r, data-visualization

I want to change the name for facet_grid based on the variable name, and also change the Index title into Date. Currently, I have this data frame:

```
structure(list(Google = c(75L, 84L, 81L, 82L, 78L, 83L, 79L, 
79L, 75L, 74L, 72L, 74L, 66L, 70L, 65L, 67L, 69L, 61L, 62L, 55L, 
72L, 59L, 72L, 62L, 69L, 71L, 62L, 67L, 68L, 65L, 74L, 71L, 69L, 
74L, 67L, 67L, 61L, 59L, 66L, 73L, 71L, 71L, 66L, 69L, 74L, 72L, 
100L, 86L, 79L, 87L, 94L, 96L, 43L, 37L, 42L, 44L, 44L, 42L, 
45L, 45L, 41L, 42L, 40L, 42L, 39L, 36L, 36L, 35L, 34L, 32L, 29L, 
36L, 33L, 37L, 34L, 43L, 38L, 37L, 43L, 49L, 50L, 43L, 42L, 41L, 
39L, 47L, 45L, 40L, 39L, 37L, 52L, 61L, 49L, 46L, 44L, 40L, 42L, 
64L, 66L, 83L, 100L, 72L, 78L, 74L, 78L, 45L, 43L, 40L, 39L, 
35L, 37L, 38L, 37L, 35L, 38L, 34L, 33L, 30L, 34L, 31L, 30L, 29L, 
32L, 34L, 29L, 32L, 31L, 100L, 64L, 42L, 46L, 46L, 41L, 38L, 
37L, 33L, 34L, 33L, 34L, 33L, 30L, 36L, 37L, 41L, 44L, 42L, 41L, 
41L, 57L, 47L, 54L, 48L, 45L, 43L, 46L, 46L, 55L, 50L, 51L, 54L, 
55L, 55L, 53L, 58L, 54L, 48L, 50L, 45L, 46L, 44L, 43L, 47L, 44L, 
44L, 42L, 44L, 42L, 42L, 46L, 54L, 48L, 46L, 53L, 47L, 45L, 45L, 
48L, 47L, 48L, 43L, 42L, 43L, 41L, 45L, 45L, 100L, 63L, 49L, 
54L, 47L, 87L, 60L, 73L, 63L, 53L, 51L, 62L, 58L, 53L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 19L, 21L, 81L, 100L, 62L, 38L, 36L, 29L, 37L, 27L, 22L, 
23L, 21L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 23L, 20L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 21L, 20L, 
18L, 21L, 22L, 20L, 18L, 18L, 20L, 19L, 17L, 19L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 23L, 25L, 24L, 32L, 26L, 25L, 24L, 27L, 29L, 25L, 60L, 
59L, 57L, 55L, 56L, 56L, 62L, 64L, 57L, 58L, 58L, 57L, 59L, 53L, 
69L, 54L, 53L, 60L, 47L, 53L, 54L, 52L, 52L, 48L, 56L, 52L, 56L, 
52L, 47L, 56L, 100L, 78L, 59L, 49L, 62L, 59L, 57L, 53L, 49L, 
54L, 54L, 54L, 51L, 61L, 64L, 70L, 85L, 62L, 68L, 76L, 85L, 85L, 
88L, 78L, 85L, 81L, 77L, 87L, 78L, 100L, 92L), Yahoo = c(80L, 
87L, 85L, 83L, 82L, 86L, 86L, 87L, 83L, 82L, 79L, 79L, 79L, 78L, 
78L, 80L, 76L, 72L, 73L, 72L, 80L, 74L, 76L, 72L, 74L, 82L, 80L, 
77L, 80L, 77L, 78L, 77L, 77L, 82L, 76L, 73L, 72L, 73L, 77L, 76L, 
76L, 81L, 81L, 80L, 80L, 82L, 100L, 86L, 88L, 90L, 99L, 94L, 
62L, 61L, 62L, 61L, 59L, 62L, 62L, 61L, 62L, 60L, 59L, 60L, 57L, 
56L, 57L, 55L, 54L, 52L, 55L, 55L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 61L, 63L, 66L, 
62L, 59L, 66L, 63L, 61L, 59L, 59L, 64L, 61L, 59L, 57L, 57L, 74L, 
82L, 69L, 64L, 63L, 63L, 69L, 77L, 80L, 97L, 100L, 85L, 88L, 
92L, 97L, 67L, 67L, 65L, 63L, 60L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 58L, 58L, 56L, 
58L, 56L, 56L, 52L, 51L, 52L, 56L, 58L, 54L, 53L, 52L, 100L, 
82L, 65L, 71L, 61L, 61L, 57L, 56L, 53L, 53L, 51L, 54L, 53L, 53L, 
58L, 59L, 57L, 57L, 60L, 61L, 60L, 63L, 62L, 73L, 67L, 64L, 64L, 
65L, 68L, 69L, 63L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 60L, 61L, 63L, 62L, 59L, 59L, 
57L, 57L, 56L, 55L, 54L, 56L, 56L, 53L, 52L, 57L, 56L, 56L, 60L, 
55L, 54L, 57L, 53L, 54L, 52L, 53L, 55L, 53L, 50L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 
51L, 52L, 100L, 64L, 57L, 58L, 58L, 76L, 67L, 74L, 65L, 64L, 
64L, 66L, 69L, 59L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 45L, 78L, 100L, 81L, 
65L, 64L, 65L, 68L, 55L, 51L, 49L, 48L, 44L, 44L, 48L, 48L, 46L, 
45L, 44L, 45L, 42L, 45L, 43L, 44L, 47L, 48L, 44L, 42L, 42L, 45L, 
60L, 49L, 50L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 48L, 49L, 51L, 55L, 52L, 58L, 51L, 
51L, 53L, 55L, 58L, 54L, 70L, 70L, 67L, 68L, 65L, 72L, 73L, 72L, 
70L, 74L, 73L, 72L, 70L, 66L, 66L, 63L, 62L, 62L, 63L, 62L, 64L, 
63L, 62L, 62L, 65L, 64L, 60L, 81L, 69L, 67L, 100L, 73L, 67L, 
62L, 69L, 64L, 66L, 64L, 62L, 63L, 65L, 67L, 65L, 69L, 71L, 74L, 
82L, 74L, 74L, 85L, 87L, 87L, 86L, 87L, 100L, 81L, 81L, 83L, 
83L, 83L, 83L), Bing = c(34L, 58L, 82L, 53L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 36L, 
34L, 37L, 37L, 42L, 78L, 45L, 46L, 43L, 41L, 39L, 40L, 49L, 100L, 
54L, 78L, 37L, 38L, 40L, 43L, 39L, 38L, 38L, 37L, 67L, 74L, 59L, 
40L, 38L, 43L, 47L, 43L, 40L, 36L, 80L, 55L, 38L, 40L, 65L, 80L, 
51L, 42L, 49L, 59L, 43L, 23L, 19L, 19L, 16L, 16L, 20L, 16L, 14L, 
17L, 17L, 18L, 15L, 16L, 27L, 19L, 16L, 16L, 20L, 16L, 27L, 17L, 
16L, 17L, 54L, 25L, 19L, 18L, 30L, 34L, 24L, 23L, 19L, 17L, 84L, 
27L, 21L, 19L, 17L, 63L, 36L, 20L, 18L, 17L, 19L, 24L, 20L, 32L, 
100L, 31L, 23L, 23L, 21L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 12L, 10L, 11L, 9L, 15L, 
11L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
20L, 12L, 100L, 17L, 14L, 72L, 24L, 29L, 15L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 
10L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 29L, 25L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 21L, 11L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 16L, 9L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 11L, 16L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 
17L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 
9L, 100L, 16L, 12L, 8L, 15L, 34L, 13L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 11L, 11L, 22L, 14L, 11L, 100L, 40L, 28L, 16L, 16L, 31L, 16L, 
30L, 12L, 14L, 21L, 13L, 12L, 42L, 28L, 14L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 19L, 
13L, 10L, 13L, 16L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 33L, 16L, 14L, 17L, 11L, 
14L, 11L, 12L, 21L, 30L, 36L, 15L, 20L, 13L, 11L, 12L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 20L, 16L, 12L, 12L, 30L, 20L, 15L, 
14L, 12L, 15L, 13L, 24L, 30L, 14L, 12L, 22L, 20L, 15L, 18L, 13L, 
14L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 41L, 100L, 28L, 14L, 17L, 27L, 12L, 13L, 
13L, 14L, 14L, 16L, 12L, 16L, 13L, 30L, 18L, 13L, 20L, 23L, 14L, 
13L, 28L, 66L, 67L, 100L, 65L, 72L, 72L, 65L, 86L, 60L)), row.names = c(NA, 
322L), class = "data.frame")
```

and this code that I use for plotting the data

```
ggarrange(p1 +theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
                    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
                    strip.text.y = element_blank()),
          p2 +theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
                    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
                    strip.text.y = element_blank()),
          p3 + theme(strip.text.y = element_blank()),
          ncol = 1, nrow = 3,common.legend=TRUE, legend="bottom",
          labels=c("1","2","3"),
          hjust=c(0,0,0),
          vjust=c(1,0.5,0.1),
          font.label = list(size = 10))
```

Trying to find similar problem in stackoverflow but no luck.

Code currently produce this graph

[image]

But i want to change the facet name as to reflect my variables.

Comment: To change 'Index' you can use: `xlab = "Date"`. It would be helpful to see a reprex of your data for the Y-axis labeling. What do you want the Y-axis to be labeled as? You can type `dput(data_frame_name)` into your console and paste the output to provide a reprex.

Comment: @Matt solved the problem for the x title. the y axis should be the title of each graph : Google, Yahoo, and Bing

Comment: and my data frame is in integer

Comment: I think you need to change the line: `labels=c("1","2","3")` to `labels=c("Google","Yahoo","Bing")`. You didn't provide your full code, so I don't have the objects that you're arranging with `ggarrange` (like p1, p2, p3).